# Atualização de dados no sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server

Desde ontem venho tendo um problema muito estranho na hora e atualizar dados no meu BD.
Sempre consegui fazer atualização de dados, mas não tenho mais conseguido com esse comando:

```
if(isset($_POST['salvarNao'])){
    $acordoo = $_POST['acordoo'];
    $dataProximaAudi = $_POST['dataProximaAudiencia'];

    $dataP = explode('-', $dataProximaAudi);
    $dataProximaAudi = $dataP[0].$dataP[1].$dataP[2];

    $sqlNao = "UPDATE [RDO].[dbo].[reclamatoria] SET acordoNAO='$acordoo', dataProximaAudiencia='$dataProximaAudi' WHERE ID='$id_reclamatoria'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlNao );
}
```

Será que tem algo de errado nesse meu código?
a data atual que tenho no banco é 1900-01-01 00:00:00 00, campo datetime

Comment: Aparece algum erro? o update funciona direto no banco? se `$dataP` está no formatado `yyyy-mm-dd` não precisa do explode.

Comment: Nenhum erro é apresentado e se rodo direto no banco, funciona! Atualiza!

Comment: UPDATE [RDO].[dbo].[reclamatoria] SET acordoNAO='Não', dataProximaAudiencia='20150122' WHERE ID='96'

Comment: Você tem a variável `$id_reclamatoria` setada? De um `echo` na `query` para ver o que ela está montando.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma atualização por partes. Tentei primeiro atualizar um campo, acordoNAO e não funcionou, e depois dataProximaAudiencia e funcionou. Então o problema está no campo acordoNAO.

Comment: Não sei porque, mas o campo acordoNAO, não está aceitando "~" (til), sendo que ele é um campo nvarchar(3)... Tive que tirar o til pra ele entrar no banco.